# function to stop/reboot the computer from a web application

Tags: java, linux, reboot

I used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot")` to restart the computer, but there are two problems:

1. I use the `HandlerInterceptor's` afterCompletion method to log the log, so that the log may not be recorded successfully;
2. In the execute reboot command If you refresh the web application immediately, you will report that the MySQL database is not connected, because the web application has not stopped yet, but the MySQL first receives the reboot signal and stops.
   Do you have any good suggestions?

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "system_set", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       @AccessLog(value = "操作计算机", additional = {"{0=关闭计算机,1=重启计算机,2=关闭网卡}"})
       @ResponseBody
       public JsonObj sysOper(@RequestParam Integer num) {
           // 1:重启计算机/0:关闭计算机/2：关闭网卡
           if (num == 1) {
               NetWorkService.rebootSystem();
           } else if (num == 0) {
               NetWorkService.shutdownSystem();
           } else if (num == 2) {
               NetWorkService.rebootNetwork();
           } else {
               return new JsonObj(false);
           }

           return new JsonObj(true);
       }



   public static void rebootSystem() {
           String execCommand =  "reboot";
           try {
               Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execCommand);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               logger.error("failed reboot system", e);
           }
       }




   <mvc:interceptor>
               <mvc:mapping path="/**"></mvc:mapping>
               <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/**" ></mvc:exclude-mapping>
               <bean class="cn.com.web.interceptors.AccessLogger" />
           </mvc:interceptor>
   ```

Comment: so you want to `reboot` your system from a web browser - sounds dangerous, sounds like you must also be running your webserver as root.

Comment: Not necessarily.  On some systems `shutdown` is a link to `systemctl`, and it can be configured so that a non-root user can initiate a shutdown.

Comment: Welcome on the SO! Pro tip: if you ask a question, don't use any non-English text in it. It confuses the answerers and the reviewers, because not understanding that part of the question, they also won't know if it is important or not. Ne bonyolítsd az életüket, ha nem muszáj :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you want to log the reboot command to the database in case you want to reboot the system, i am correct? 
If it's the case then you should write customized code to log to database before calling NetWorkService.rebootSystem();
Something like will do:

```
if (num == 1) {
        LogService.LogRebootEvent(); 
        NetWorkService.rebootSystem();
    } else if (num == 0) {
        NetWorkService.shutdownSystem();
    } else if (num == 2) {
        NetWorkService.rebootNetwork();
    } else {
        return new JsonObj(false);
    }
```

Comment: This method is logged, but it can't be recorded if there is an exception in the next code. Another problem is that if I execute the command like this, will the backup be executed later? What is the underlying principle of runtime.exec executing commands?          String execCommand = "supervisorctl stop cra && reboot";  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c",execCommand});